# Best way to change gridTemplateColumns width on hover, in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

CSS Grid + React JS
Let's say I have a very basic header and sidebar. And on hovering the sidebar I want the width of the sidebar to grow to 300px. How could I approach that?

React

```
<div className="app">
    <div className="header"></div>
    <div className="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "menu header";
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}
.sidebar {
  grid-area: menu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reacts
onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave attributes

so it would be something like this:

```
<div className="sidebar" 
  onMouseEnter={() => Make Width 300px}
  onMouseLeave={() => reset width}>
</div>
```